# an empty .git/info/sparse-checkout is not the same as a missing one, but the opposite, why?

Tags: git, sparse-matrix, git-checkout

First `core.sparsecheckout` is set to `true`.

And I created an empty `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file. This causes I'm not able to checkout a new branch recently fetched from remote.

Then I tried to delete the empty `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file, and now I can checkout.

I understand the fact, and I know I can include `/*` in `.git/info/sparse-checkout` to make it work.

I just wonder why? what's the rational behind this? isn't it confusing?

As to me, both an empty `sparse-checkout` file, and a missing one, are saying: "nothing is specified to go with sparse checkout", therefore git should checkout everything.

I guess what I need is a more convincing explanation of the current choice, not how this is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Not really: if the `.git/info/sparse-checkout` is present, the sparse checkout mechasnism kicks in, and look for files/folder to checkout.
See [unpack-trees.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/97b8860c071898d9e162678ea1035a8ced2f8b1f/unpack-trees.c#L1024-L1025):

```
if (!o->skip_sparse_checkout) {
    if (add_excludes_from_file_to_list(
          git_path("info/sparse-checkout"), "", 0, &el, 0) < 0)
```

If it finds no files/folders to checkout (because `.git/info/sparse-checkout` is empty), it checks out... nothing.

But if `.git/info/sparse-checkout` isn't there in the first place, this isn't a sparse checkout at all, and Git would check out everything.

---

Note that, before Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git sparse-checkout init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb754fe0b8b9ec2494fe355f1f36a05ff2ccbb38/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt) "<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout))</sup>failed to write into `$GIT_DIR/info` directory when the repository was created without one, which has been corrected to auto-create it.

See [commit 7f44842](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f44842ac198c8fbf76c513cb69b66bdc54d59e8) (21 Jan 2022) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bb754fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb754fe0b8b9ec2494fe355f1f36a05ff2ccbb38), 09 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`sparse-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f44842ac198c8fbf76c513cb69b66bdc54d59e8): create leading directory
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jose Lopes</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> When creating the sparse-checkout file, Git does not create the leading directory, "`$GIT_DIR/info`", if it does not exist.
> This causes problems if the repository does not have that directory.
> Therefore, ensure that the leading directory is created.
>
> This is the only "open" in [`builtin/sparse-checkout.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f44842ac198c8fbf76c513cb69b66bdc54d59e8/builtin/sparse-checkout.c) that does not have a leading directory check.
> (The other one in `write_patterns_and_update()` does.)
>
> Note that the test needs to explicitly specify a template when running "[`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f44842ac198c8fbf76c513cb69b66bdc54d59e8/Documentation/git-init.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> because the default template used in the tests has the info/ directory included.

Comment: thank you. I guess I understand how this is implemented, but my question/concern is more about the rational. To me it's more natural to say that both an empty `sparse-checkout` file, and a missing one, are saying: "nothing is specified to go with sparse checkout", then I expect both would *checkout everything*. for now I have to remember that the default setting for a missing `sparse-checkout` file is one with `/*`, but not an empty one, given `core.sparsecheckout` is true

Comment: @ryenus I understand, but here, the very presence of `.git/info/sparse-checkout` does *not* mean "nothing be specified to go with sparse checkout" (as it is currently implemented)